# nexus ldap config,verify user mapping success, verify login error

Tags: ldap, nexus

nexus ldap config,verify user mapping success, 
[verify login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScMX5.png)

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Inw.png)

and the ldap roles can get from roles->create role->external role mapping->ldap->[mapped roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY4sb.png)

the log as below:

> 2018-09-27 20:20:11,402+0800 ERROR [qtp1824645432-178]  admin
>   org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet - Failed to
>   invoke action method: ldap_LdapServer.verifyLogin, java-method:
>   org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.internal.ui.LdapServerComponent.verifyLogin
>   java.lang.Exception: Failed to connect to LDAP Server: No such user: A
>   user with username 'root' does not exist  at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor230.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.ldap.internal.ui.LdapServerComponent.verifyLogin(LdapServerComponent.groovy:252)
>     at
>   com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionMeteredInterceptor.java:49)
>     at
>   com.palominolabs.metrics.guice.TimedInterceptor.invoke(TimedInterceptor.java:47)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.validation.internal.ValidationInterceptor.invoke(ValidationInterceptor.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.proceed(AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.invoke(AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.java:36)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.proceed(AopAllianceMethodInvocationAdapter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.authz.aop.AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizingAnnotationMethodInterceptor.java:68)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.guice.aop.AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.invoke(AopAllianceMethodInterceptorAdapter.java:36)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor539.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeJavaMethod(DispatcherBase.java:142)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.invokeMethod(DispatcherBase.java:133)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet$3.invokeMethod(ExtDirectServlet.java:233)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.dispatcher.DispatcherBase.dispatch(DispatcherBase.java:63)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.StandardRequestProcessorBase.dispatchStandardMethod(StandardRequestProcessorBase.java:73)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.JsonRequestProcessor.processIndividualRequest(JsonRequestProcessor.java:502)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.JsonRequestProcessor.processIndividualRequestsInThisThread(JsonRequestProcessor.java:150)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.processor.standard.json.JsonRequestProcessor.process(JsonRequestProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.router.RequestRouter.processJsonRequest(RequestRouter.java:83)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.DirectJNgineServlet.processRequest(DirectJNgineServlet.java:617)
>     at
>   com.softwarementors.extjs.djn.servlet.DirectJNgineServlet.doPost(DirectJNgineServlet.java:580)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.extdirect.internal.ExtDirectServlet.doPost(ExtDirectServlet.java:138)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:286)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:276)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:181)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicServletPipeline.service(DynamicServletPipeline.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:112)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.executeChain(SecurityFilter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.security.SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   com.sonatype.nexus.licensing.internal.LicensingRedirectFilter.doFilter(LicensingRedirectFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:97)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:68)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.EnvironmentFilter.doFilter(EnvironmentFilter.java:101)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.internal.web.HeaderPatternFilter.doFilter(HeaderPatternFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:82)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.DynamicFilterPipeline.dispatch(DynamicFilterPipeline.java:104)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:135)
>     at
>   org.sonatype.nexus.bootstrap.osgi.DelegatingFilter.doFilter(DelegatingFilter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1629)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: You need to use the LDAP username - and typically 'root' is not a user in many LDAP directories. Can you try a known LDAP username ?

Comment: @mvreijn the 'root' is my LDAP username, the verify user mapping included it.

Comment: i use the ldap for my gitlab system, and the 'root' and other user in LDAP login success.

Answer (score 0):

my detail config as below:
[realms config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwo99.png)

[connection config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbndl.png)

[user and group config,and veriry success image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2Vax.png)

[verify all ldap user , can not found the username from ldap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcYgx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to log into the LDAP server with the given proxy user `uid=admin,ou=system`? Because I think that DN should be `uid=admin,ou=system,dc=dinfo,dc=com` instead.

When the proxy user fails, all user logins will likely fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `User ID attribute` with an attribute that corresponds to your user name (e.g. `cn`). If that does not help check the logs of your LDAP provider and analyze the search query.